# Hyper-v 2016 won't connect remotely

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, windows-server-core

It worked perfectly before I changed my password because the password has expired. Now I get this [alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b46yJ.png) when I try to connect to my VM server. I can't figure out why it is problem now.

Answer (score 1):

If hyper-v services are up and running there are some possible solutions:

1- you are in a domain environment and using local user, when you have changed your local user password it does not match your domain user password any more.

explanation:
Let us say you have two users user1@domain.com (domain user) and user1@localhost (local user) on your machine. password for both users was the same, when you try to connect remotely you will by entering your password hypver-v machine will check if user exist on the domain and has the same password, if both condition met you will be able to login if not you will get the error as shown in your attached image.

2- Use the Services snap-in or Sc config command-line tool to reconfigure the service to start automatically. for more information refer to this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/best-practices-analyzer/the-hyper-v-virtual-machine-management-service-must-be-running

3- make sure turn on virtual platform on bios ==>  from turn windows features on or off expand hyper-v and enable hyper-v platform (Must) ==> restart your machine it should be working without problem.

4- check Windows firewall